# page-break-before:avoid on media print not working

Tags: html, css

While trying to diagnose issues with page breaks using wkhtmltopdf a created a [contrived.html](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/horriblyUnpythonic/1e041006eac5660200274ea0e4a175af/raw/d05846c4147b5d8cefece0b42c51ec62cdd71b7c/contrived.html) document that doesn't appear to follow my stated `page-break-*` rules.

The last line on the first page of that document, if I open it in the chrome print dialog is one of the read div sections. It has the `page-break-after:avoid` style set and the first chunk on the second page has the `page-break-before:avoid` style set. I assume that either of these (especially combined) would mean that that red text should be the first thing on the second page, but it doesn't appear to work like that.

Is there something I'm misunderstanding about the way that media print functions, or how those styles are applied?

I've tried various elements, div, span, tables, adding `!important`, but none of it seems to behave he way I'd expect.

Image for ease of use
[image: Image for ease of use]

Comment: Bad news : https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-page-break

Comment: Almost all browser : Does not support avoid for page-break-before & page-break-after (only page-break-inside).

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with the browsers — ALL browsers — not your code. In my css stylesheet, I have specified

```
@media print {
    h3, h4 { page-break-after: avoid; }
}
```

But my code has absolutely no effect when I print using any browser that I have. I even tried iCab, a browser not included by [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/css-page-break) (the link provided by @Bazaim), and it also did not honor the css @media print style direction.